# How to evaluate $ \int_{0}^{{\frac{\pi}{2}}} \cos(ax) \cos(a\cos(bx)) \, dx$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals

> **Evaluate**
>
> $$ \int_{0}^{{\frac{\pi}{2}}} \cos(ax) \cos(a\cos(bx)) \, dx \ ; \ a,b \in \mathbb{Z^+}$$

I tried taylor series and finding a reduction formula, but couldn't evaluate the integral. Please avoid contour integration as I don't know that yet.

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Are $a,b$ any real numbers?

Comment: @mrprottolo They are positive integers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I doubt that there's a "closed-form" formula.  In the case $b=1$ with $a$ an odd positive integer, it seems to be:

$$ (-1)^{(a-1)/2} \dfrac{1 - \text{LommelS1}(1,a,a)}{a} $$

EDIT: if $a$ is an even integer and $b$ is an integer, by symmetry your integral is
$$ \dfrac{1}{4} \int_0^{2\pi} \cos(ax) \cos(a \cos(bx))\; dx $$
and we can express the second cosine in a power series:
$$ \dfrac{1}{4} \sum_{n=0}^\infty  \dfrac{a^n}{n!} \int_0^{2\pi} \cos(ax) \cos(bx)^n\; dx$$
and $\cos(bx)^n$ can be expressed as a combination of $\cos(jbx)$ for $0 \le j \le n$.  If $a$ is not a multiple of $b$, then by orthogonality the result will be $0$.

Comment: What is orthogonality?

Comment: $\int_0^{2\pi} \cos(mx) \cos(nx)\; dx = 0$ for nonnegative integers $m \ne n$.  Look up **Fourier series**.