# Evaluate $\int_{0}^{\pi/2} \cos(a\cos (bx))~dx$

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

I fail to evaluate $$\int_{0}^{\pi/2} \cos(a\cos (bx))~dx$$ where $a,b$ are constants.
Can anyone help me please?

This question come from a problem in condensed matter physics.
For non-interacting lattice electron the band energy is $E_k = -2J\cos
(k)$.
When we try to calculate some global physical quantities, the form $\int_{0}^{\pi/2} \cos(a\cos (bx))~dx$ appears, because the phase of the wavefunction is $e^{-iEt}$.

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: It may be helpful to consider the Bessel function of the first kind, as follows: $J_{0}(1) = \frac{1}{\pi} \int_{0}^{\pi} \cos(-\sin(x)) \text{ dx}=\frac{1}{\pi} \int_{0}^{\pi} \cos(\cos(x)) \text{ dx}$

Comment: This question is similar: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1782471/how-to-evaluate-int-0-frac-pi2-cosax-cosa-cosbx-dx

Comment: Try expanding the integrand into a power series in $\cos bx$. Integrate the power series term-by-term.

Answer (score 1):

First, we let $u=bx$, and thus $dx=\tfrac{1}{b}du$. Changing the limits of integration, we get
$$I=\frac{1}{b}\int_0^{\tfrac{b\pi}{2}}\cos(a\cos{}u)du.$$
Then, we use the identity that
$$\cos(t\cos{}x)=J_0(t)+2\sum_{k\geq{}1}(-1)^kJ_{2k}(t)\cos(2kx)$$
where $J_0(x)$ is the bessel function of the first kind (identity given in [source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Composition_of_trigonometric_functions))
and find that
$$I=\frac{1}{b}\int_0^{\frac{b\pi}{2}}J_0(a)du+\frac{2}{b}\sum_{k\geq{}1}(-1)^kJ_{2k}(a)\int_0^{\frac{b\pi}{2}}\cos(2ku)du.$$
Evaluating, we find
$$I=\frac{\pi}{2}J_0(a)+\frac{1}{b}\sum_{k\geq{}1}\frac{(-1)^k}{k}J_{2k}(a)\sin(bk\pi).$$
Now, I find it useful to mention that if $b\in\mathbb{Z}$, then $\sin(bk\pi)=0$, and thus $I$ simplifies greatly to be
$$I=\frac{\pi}{2}J_0(a).$$